# How to deploy or Host a NESTJS API in CPANEL NODEJS server?

Tags: hosting, cpanel, nestjs

For the past three months I have been using NESTJS for Creating REST API. Now I need to host it in a Cpanel Nodejs server.

kindly let me know how I can host it?

Comment: have you found a way to do so?

Comment: Till now I didn't find any solution for that! But I am using herokuapp to host